# ASP.Net MVC EF Map To Junction Table With Three Primary Keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having the hardest time figuring this out.  I am using MVC 4 and Code First Entity Framework.  I have three classes.  They are Users, Roles, and Project.  A user can have many projects and for a particular project, a user can have a particular role.  I am using a junction table to combine the three tables.  Here is an example of the Junction Table:

```
public class UserRolesinProject
{
     [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
     public int UserId { get; set;}
     [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
     public int RoleId  { get; set;}
     [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
     public int ProjectId  { get; set;}

}
```

Here are samples of each of the classes

```
public class DBUser
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set;}
    public string UserName { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection< UserRolesinProject > Roles { get; set; }
}

public class DBRole
{
    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set;}
    public string RoleName { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection< UserRolesinProject > Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
     [Key]
     public int ProjectId { get; set;}
     public string ProjectName { get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection< UserRolesinProject > Users { get; set; }
}
```

Lastly a sample of the context class

```
    Public DBSet<DBUser>Users {get; set;}
    Public DBSet<DBRoles>Roles {get; set;}
    Public DBSet<Project>Projects {get; set;}
    Public DBSet<UserRolesInProject>UserRolesProjects {get; set;}
```

So at the moment this builds and the tables are created when I use the package manager console to update the database.  What I wanted to achieve was if I do a LINQ statement from the User I would like to retrieve all the projects that the User is assigned to and the respective role.  Right now, I’m just getting the ids of each field, which is from the junction table and the mapping that I did in each individual class to the junction table.  I thought the result would be they all would be joined.  What am I doing wrong?  I searched and viewed different examples, but they were all for two PK columns not three.  Are my tables wrong?  Did I set them up in an inefficient way?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Just to be clear: you **don't** have three primary keys - a relational table only ever has **ONE** primary key - in your case, that **ONE** primary key is just made up from three columns.